# Equivalent of old-style ffmpeg's silenceremove in newest version of ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

In the past, I've used the audio filter `silenceremove=0:0:-45dB:-1:1:-45dB`. It's worked great, but upon downloading a fresh copy of ffmpeg unto another computer, I found that this command no longer works. Examining the wiki reveals that the syntax for the `silenceremove` filter has been changed.

Instead of just using an old version of ffmpeg, I'd like to translate this old command to the new so that I don't have to mess with getting a compatible old version. However, since I can't find the wiki entry for the old `silenceremove`, It's proving quites difficult to try and translate.

Comment: Which is your old version?

Comment: @Gyan The nightly build of September 21, 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`silenceremove=0:0:-45dB:-1:1:-45dB` for September 21, 2017 build translates to `silenceremove=0:0:-45dB:0:'any':-1:1:-45dB` for current (Nov 26, 2018) build.

Two options are new. The old option `leave_silence` is factorized into `start_silence` and `stop_silence`, with the former inserted after your third value in the original string. The second option is `start_mode` which sets which all channels need to be silent in order for the filter to register the start of a silent segment. Choices are `any` (default) and `all`. This option appears after `start_silence`.

Comment: Please use named options, that way it is more future proof.